# lazyinitalizationexception with wildfly 14: could not initialize proxy - the owning session was closed

Tags: spring, hibernate, wildfly, jta, transactional

If I run my code with wildfly 14 server I get following excpetion. The same code worked with wildfly 13. Where could be the problem?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [ch.example.tool.entity.Benutzer#12] - the owning Session was closed
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getIdentifier(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getProxyIdentifier(SessionImpl.java:1752)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getContextEntityIdentifier(SessionImpl.java:1743)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.nullSafeSet(EntityType.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2868)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3307)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3229)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
    ... 122 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to explicitly load the lazy proxy reference for the merge operation in Wildfly 14. Like this it works.

Wildfly 13 and before:

```
@Transactional
public class VergleichDAOImpl implements VergleichDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    @Override
    public void save(Vergleich vergleich) {     

        if(vergleich.getId() == null) {
            em.persist(vergleich);
        } else {
            em.merge(vergleich);
        }
    }
```

Wildfly 14

```
@Transactional
public class VergleichDAOImpl implements VergleichDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    @Override
    public void save(Vergleich vergleich) {     

        if(vergleich.getId() == null) {
            em.persist(vergleich);
        } else {
            Benutzer benutzer  = em.find(Benutzer.class, vergleich.getBenutzer().getId());
            vergleich.setBenutzer(benutzer);
            em.merge(vergleich);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is closing the session, in my similar problem it is Spring, are you using Spring. The solution you are proposing is a workaround, I think the actual root of the cause needs to be resolved. I have written to Hibernate, but they suggest it is a Spring problem. Maybe it is a Wildfly problem.

Did you resolve this, I have the exact same problem. The workaround that you gave is not plauseble for a fullblown enterprise project. I'm using Wildfly 15, upgrade from Wildfly 10, is it a bug in Wildfly?

Comment: You are right my solution is only a workaround. Sorry I didn't investigate more time to find out the origin of the problem. Perhaps there is bugfix in WF15?

Answer (score 0):

I also opted for a workaround, all entities @ManyToOne have been annotated with @NotAudited, so Envers does not try to load them after entityManager is closed. Works for now, seems to be a Hibernate bug.

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-envers-throws-the-owning-session-was-closed-with-spring-5-1-and-hibernate-orm-5-3/1941/12), setting `hibernate.jpa.compliance.proxy=false` in your configuration may be the solution (as Wildfly may be setting this to true).